# Hot network questions have broken icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hot-questions

Right now on the main site in hot network questions I can see broken icons like these:

[image]

I'm using Safari Version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8) on macOS 10.13.6.

I can see the same issue on gaming.stackexchange.com and its meta, but not on SO meta!

Comment: No repro on Chrome/Win10

Comment: Repros for me with Edge and Chrome on Win10

Comment: Seeing a similar issue on Chrome on Mac OS: https://imgur.com/3SkWzJz The movies.SE icon is being displayed for money.SE, and the tor.SE icon is being displayed for tex.SE. I'm seeing the issue on Stack Overflow, but not on SO meta or SE meta.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @JustinLardinois.  Firefox 62, Windows 7.

Comment: This issue on Meta.SE: [incorrect icons on hot network questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315468/289905).

Comment: no repro. Mac OS 10.13.4 running FF 62.0

Comment: happening again ... I guess I'll wait a bit ...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This happens sometimes when we roll out a new set of icons due to how our build process works. I'll see what I can do about kicking the affected cachebreakers, but either way it'll resolve itself ... eventually. Caching is fun!

Comment: ok, http://shouldiblamecaching.com/, thanks

Comment: I don't know... it's six days later and still a problem.

Comment: And now another six days.

Comment: So, about 15 minutes ago I got a string of Varnish Cache errors and when it came back, the icons are in the right place. So I'm guessing that the cache was kicked. Thanks, in case it was you.