# Icons out of sync in achievements popup and other places

Tags: bug

I was expecting this problem to resolve itself eventually but it's been over a week now, and the icons are still wrong. I checked the generated HTML and it is clear that the offsets in the icons image are not in sync with the image itself.

I probably should have reported this bug earlier, but I waited a couple of days to see if the caches would sync. It's not the same bug as the problem with the achievements drop-down not updating; the icons issue was present long before that happened, and it is still present now after the queue apparently cleared.

I see the same problem on desktop and mobile and on different browsers.

I'm accessing the internet from Perú, in case it's a caching problem with your CDN.

This one is from my achievements drop-down. The Travel icon should be Unix&Linux:
[image: From my achievements drop-down]

This one is from my profile page on SO:

[image: From my SO profile page]

Comment: @yivi: I don't think that's the same bug. My achievement drop down now shows all recent achievements (afaik) and was the result of a stuck queue, aiui. This is almost certainly a caching problem and was present long before the queue was jammed (and is still present now, after the queue cleared.)

Comment: Showing or not showing the achievements may also be a caching related. Considering they have been having problems with achivements notifications for a week as well, it would surprise me if both issues weren't the same. But I'll retract the dupe vote.

Comment: @yivi: From the discussion on the achievements bug, it seems clear that it was not cache related.

Comment: Me, I'm still betting this issue and the other issue are very closely related. But I guess we'll find out. :)

Comment: @yivi: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315841/212668 .

Comment: I asked a question with this issue presenting itself in the "Hot Network Questions" list yesterday but was voted to close as a duplicate, so I deleted it (since it did seem like a duplicate). On a closer look though, it seems that it is a different issue, and the issue is been for at least a week, so I don't think it's caching

Comment: @yivi: FYI https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synch That's the way I've always spelled it. I also spell labour with a u. Sosumi.

Comment: @Lamak: a week is a long time for a caching problem but I've had problems with CloudFlare before, which I'm pretty sure were specific to the cache from which they serve Perú. That's just based on my theory that if the problem were visible in Certain Other Countries, it would get fixed.

Comment: @rici ah, didn't realize this issue isn't presenting in the US, but makes sense that it hasn't been reported then

Comment: @lamak: I don't know that it isn't presenting in the U.S. It's just a theory. (The other issues I had with CF definitely were not present in the U.S., but I did find references to them in some other countries.)

Comment: It's a good theory. Coincidentally, I'm in Chile

Comment: @Lamak. Lo sé. Vi tu perfil.

Comment: See the answer on [Hot network questions have broken icons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374126/7296893). This very likely is just caching after a change to the sprites again.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth but the icons aren't "broken", and the mixup is consistent (unix is shown as travel)

Comment: @Lamak Consistent fits, it's desync between the CSS and the png. The [png](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=ab06c2b4b2e8) contains a huge list of icons, the CSS indicates which area of the png should get displayed for which icon. If the versions don't match up because one is cached while the other isn't, you get this, and they're either shifted or just consistently the wrong icon.

Comment: @erik: that would be my analysis, too, but I think that if a cache doesn't synch in a week and a half, it's worth a bug report. Particularly given the possibility that the out of synch cache might be external and the problem might not be visible to the SO crew.

Comment: Yeah, the duration is certainly odd, combined with the fact that it's multiple machines, I think it's good you've reported it. Usually very hard to track down though, some ISPs even do some caching on hot resources, but they usually don't last for weeks.

Comment: @Lamak: So, about 15 minutes ago I got a string of Varnish Cache errors and when it came back, the icons are in the right place. So I'm guessing that the cache was kicked. Interestingly, the Varnish cache identified itself as SCL, which I presume is a geocode. So I'll bet your icons are now ok, too.

Comment: @rici yup, you are right, it's ok for me now